# JavaScript file size over 1.4 MB after executing webpack

Tags: webpack-3

Using `"lodash": "^4.17.5",`

Why is Lodash that big after doing : `webpack` ?

It looks like the sourceMapping is bloating the file...

[image]

---

```
sourceURL=[module]\n// 
sourceMappingURL=data:application/json;charset=utf-8;base64,eyJ2ZXJzaW9uIjozLCJmaWxlIjoiOC5qcyIsInNvdXJjZXMiOlsiQzpcXGluZXRwdWJcXHd3d3Jvb3RcXFdlYlBhY2tfVHlwZVNjcmlwdF9TZXR1cF9FeGFtcGxlXFxub2RlX21vZHVsZXNcXGxvZGFzaFxcbG9kYXNoLmpzIl0sInNvdXJjZXNDb250ZW50IjpbIi8qKlxuICogQGxpY2Vuc2VcbiAqIExvZGF.......
...
.
.
.
```

Comment: This doesn't seem right, the full lodash gzipped is like 24kb

Comment: Yes it's full of extra data, looks like data for source mapping to me...

Answer (score 0):

I have used `webpack` with option parameters like this:

```
webpack -d --env.dev --display-modules --progress --display-error-details"
```

The "problem" here is the `-d` flag.

> Development shortcut -d:  Equals to --debug --devtool source-map
>   --output-pathinfo

[CLI reference](https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/cli)

Removing the flag shortens the lodash.js file size to 70kb, because it does not include the source-mapping data anymore.